# ACL's ownership, permissions

Tags: permissions, samba, ownership

Problem: Whenever I write a new file/modify a file in my `www` folder, permissions and ownerships are being reset on that file, sometimes making the server unable to read the files I create. So I need to go to the terminal, set the ownerships etc. which is very tedious.

My `www` folder is accessible through Samba.
Whenever I write or modify anything to that folder I get the permissions and ownership of the file reset to `jay:jay` that can't be read by `apache`.

I looked up online and saw this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory). So I tried:

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm g:apache:rx www
sudo chmod g+s www
```

now the result is this:

```
drwxr-sr-x+ 14 jay apache  4096 Aug 15 21:09 www
```

But now whenever I try something like:

```
touch somefile.txt
```

I get these settings:

```
-rw-r--r--+ 1 jay apache 0 Aug 15 23:07 somefile.txt
```

I thought the permissions would keep the folder's permission, no?

regarding the ownership it is ok, but the permissions are not kept!

1. Say I wanted to make a 750 chmod automatic for `jay`'s writing to the folder. How would I go about that?
2. I assume the little `'s'` marks the **setgid**? Does this mean anything written inside of this folder would be given the folder's group's ownership?
3. Why doesn't it affect my files? I thought the settings of a newly created file would be just like the containing folder's `(www)` which is `rwxr-xr-x`
4. Is there a way to simply undo the `setfacl`? That is take out the little `'+'` in the permissions line?

I am running Ubuntu 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One way would be to set the `umask` value to `0022` for `jay`. [What is "umask" and how does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work) You can also set the `umask` in Samba's configuration. See [How to force group ownership on samba share?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335055/how-to-force-group-ownership-on-samba-share) for an example.
2. It does indeed stand for `setgid`. In a `setgid` folder, files and folders created inherit the group ownership, and folders inherit the `setgid` bit.
3. Settings of newly created files are set using the `umask` of the user.
4. To reset the ACL, the best way would be to use the original ACL as given by `getfacl`, since `setfacl` has  `--restore` option. Failing that, you could try to remove all extended ACLs using `setfacl -b`.

---

Regarding `sudo` and `umask`:
According to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo#Permissive_Umask):

> Sudo will union the user's umask value with its own umask (which defaults to 0022).

This should be fine (since the user's umask is `0022` as well).

Comment: may be umask value is 027 for 750 and 640 file permission.

Comment: @Letizia indeed, I misread and thought OP needed group write. OP doesn't seem to have a problem with o+rx, so a umask of 022 seems good.

Comment: is there a way to undo the setfacl? I am just unsure of this method as I don't know what I am doing. I also tried umask 027, and when I create a file, no matter what umask I give, it is created with the same permissions.

Comment: According to [setacl manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/setfacl.1.html):  Removing a named group entry from a file's ACL 'setfacl -Rx g:apache www'. I can't test it so in order to verify 'setfacl -Rx g:apache www --test' should show the results acl. If you like it @muru, you can add to complete the answer.

Comment: @Letizia thanks. But there also the `-b` option ("Remove all extended ACL entries") - is that more appropriate for resetting? I am not sure, which is why I didn't touch on that question.

Comment: @Letizia, The + doesn't go away.

Comment: yep, @muru, **-b** seems to work

Comment: I assume **umask** doesn't work for sudo commands, as I am scoping out of the user's context?

Comment: @Ted I'd think it would work, but using the target user's umask. No, it seems `sudo` can inherit the umask, or use the umask specified in `sudoers`.