# How to control group files are created with from remote users in samba (no Active Directory)

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

I have a problem I have so far not been able to find answers for on google, maybe because I am unfamiliar with terminology.

Is there a way for me to have a remote user from windows create files/folder on an ubuntu server that will give the permissions shareuser:smbgroup as oppossed to shareuser:shareuser?

- I have an Ubuntu server (20.04 updated daily) running Samba version
  4.11.6-Ubuntu. I am not using active directory at all
- I have a directory that I share
- I set up this directory to have group
  read/write permissions for the  “smbgroup”
- I made a user called
  “shareuser” to be a part of this group.

My problem is that I connect to the shared directory through a windows 10 (Build 1909) machine (no domain just the generic workgroup “workgroup” and everytime I make a file on the server through windows 10, the file/folder gets created as the sharesuser user, but instead of the smbgroup it gets created under the shareuser group (shareuser:shareuser).

Answer (score 0):

Of course, 3 minutes after i posted my question i find the answer in the related question suggestions.

[How to force group ownership on samba share?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335055/how-to-force-group-ownership-on-samba-share?rq=1)